# Screwing down toilet flange spacers with metal flange still on

Tags: toilet, flange

After raising the floor and tiling the original waste line and toilet flange is well below the top of the new floor surface. Home depot told me to use some 1/4" souix chief flange extenders / spacers. Stack them up and use silicon in between to seal them. The toilet bolts go on one of the layers and I guess I need to fill the gap that makes with more silicon. The issue I have now is that the original metal flange is still on the waste line. It is my understanding you screw the spacers to the subfloor to secure them but the metal flange is in the way. Not sure of I need to remove it or screw through them. Any advice?

Comment: Are there any holes around the metal flange to screw through? A photo would help here.

Comment: Spacers/shims for toilet flanges are usually sized/designed so that you can utilize the original flange bolt holes (you just use longer bolts). I do not like this idea of bolting to "one of the layers" that are stacked and siliconed together- bad idea.

Comment: If you're siliconing drain fittings, something's gone terribly wrong. You know **you can stack wax rings**, right? I had to use three once... That's why toilet bolts are three inches long in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "Set-Rite Flange Extender Kit" This can solve the entire problem. I believe in US they are available in Lowes, Menards and Ace Hardware. In Canada harder to find. Best bet is a larger RONA store or an ACE Hardware if you can still find one.
See this site < https://set-rite.com/frequently-asked-questions/ >